# TypeError: greetUser is not a function

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm following a set of tutorial videos.
I've added this code to main.js / on the server:

```
// import './../imports/utils';
import { greetUser } from './../imports/utils';
console.log('Log from server / main.js');
console.log(greetUser());
```

And I'm getting an error TypeError: greetUser is not a function: 
Whereas I have my utils file here:

```
console.log('Log imports / utils');

// ES6 // let

export let greetUser = function () {
  return 'Hello!';
};
```

---

```
TypeError: greetUser is not a function at meteorInstall.server.main.js (server/main.js)
```

I'm also getting this on the console:-
[image: Console log]

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short; I restarted meteor and magic happened, I got the output that I wanted from the console log on both the server and the client.

[image: Solved]